# CMake Debian Dependency on Boost Regex

Tags: dependencies, cmake, debian, boost-regex, cpack

I am currently trying to build a debian package from my project, which uses Boost-Regex. Everything is working fine except defining a dependency throug `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS`.   I don't seem to be able to figure out the right module name to put here. So far I tried the following:

```
SET (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "boost_regex")
SET (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "boost-regex")
SET (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libboost-regex") 
SET (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libboost_regex")
```

But with every version of this the Ubuntu Software Center tells me, that the couldn't resolve the dependency when trying to install the generated *.deb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my error. Leaving the answer here for others who might have the same problem: I was missing the version number, i.e. `libbost-regex1.46.1`.